# Finding the highest value of a folder, creating a new folder

Tags: batch-file

How do i create a batch file which will look into the current folders subfolders (*namingcondition: [number]_[name]*), finding the highest value of a files number, and create a new file, with that number +1.

So a folder with

> 01_CampaignSpring2017
>
> 02_CampaignSummer2017
>
> 04_CampaignWinter2017

Will give the value 5, creating the next folder with `05_[name]`

I don't have that much experience with `.bat`, but here is some of the code that i got.

```
@echo off

SET /p user_input="Insert name:"
SET name="%user_input%"

SET /a count=0
FOR /d %%i in (*) do SET /a count+=1

md %count%_%name%
```

Comment: Well I can already see you are going to have a problem when you get to 100.

Comment: In this specific case i only want to count up to 99, but maybe for the question to fit more people, there should be a solution counting to infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need code to add a leading zero to the counter. Add `100` and take the last two characters:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "next="
set "numbers=4"
SET /p user_input="Insert name:"
SET name="%user_input%"
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /on ??_*') do set /a next=10000000%%a+1
set next=%next:~-2%_%name%
md %next%
```

Also I put in a mask to just count relevant folders.

Refering to Squashman's comment: If you want three-digit numbers, just take the last three characters: `%next:~-3%`

**EDIT** Made it a bit more generic. Just change `digits` to your needs (line 4):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "next="
set "digits=4"  :: max 10
set "mask=??????????"
set "mask=!mask:~-%digits%!_*

SET /p user_input="Insert name:"
SET "name=%user_input%"
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /on %mask% 2^>nul') do set /a next=%%a+1
if not defined next ( echo empty & goto :eof )
set "next=0000000000%next%"
set "next=!next:~-%digits%!_%name%"
md "%next%"
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it to number up from the highest number. So counting files does not work based on their example because the file 03 is missing and the highest number is 04, so the output should be 05.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i know it was not a part of the question, but if the folder is empty, and there is no numbers: how would the if statement look like?
Another note, the change of %next:~-2% to %next:~-3% doesnt seem to work, with files named 001_Name

Comment: Did you think to adapt the mask from `??_*` to `???.*`? For an empty folder (or no matching subfolders), it will create a `00_whatever`. You can avoid it with `if not defined next ( echo empty & goto :eof )` the very next line after the `for`

Comment: @Stephan i see with the `???.*`, is it possible to add it to the solution?
What if the number has to go to lets say 8 digits, then we have to more than 1000 right? (is there a prettier fix for that?)
I can not get the `if not defined..` code to work. Wont `next` always be defined? (in this case next=`1000`)

Comment: yes, you are right about the `next` variable. See my edit. I Changed the logic a bit and made it generic for up to ten digits. (easily adaptable for hundreds of digits, but I doubt, that makes any sense)